# how to copy an array into a jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

When I try to copy arrays into a jagged array.  My goal is to take an array of type char,  separate the "words" into separate arrays (I use an already working function for it) and want to put them into an array.

```
static char[][] split_string(char[] str)
{
    int length = count_words(str);
    char[][] sentence = new char[length][];
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    int word = 0;
    int i = -1;
    while (i != str.Length)
    {
     i++;
     if (str[i]==' ')
     {
      end = i-1;
      char[] aux_array = substring(str, start, end);
      //issue
      aux_array.CopyTo(sentence[word], 0);
      //alternative (not working either)
      /*
      for(int j=0; j<aux_array.Length;j++)
      {
       sentence[word][j] = aux_array[j];
      }
      */
      while (str[i]==' ')
      {
       i++;
      }
      word++;
      start = i;
     }
    }
    return sentence;
   }
```

For information,
substring if of the form: substring(array, int, int) -> array
count_word is of the form: count_word(array) -> int

Comment: Hi Bazin, welcome to SO. To help others help you, please mention what issue(s) you are facing with your code? What did you expect, and what your code is doing actually? Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My goal is to take an array of type char, separate the "words" into separate arrays (I use an already working function for it) and want to put them into an array.

Then just put them into array

```
//...
sentence[word] = substring(str, start, end);
```

Note that the jagged array elements are `null` by default and you didn't allocate them, so you probably are getting null reference exception. If you really need to do a copy of the returned array, then the easiest way is to use `Array.Clone` method like this

```
sentence[word] = (char[])substring(str, start, end).Clone();
```

Comment: apparently it's working, but now i get an "out of range exception" at "if (str[i]==' ')" after i try to run it

Comment: @LoïcBazin Well, that's another problem in your code which is unrelated to the original question. You can fix it by using `while (i < str.Length &&  str[i]==' ')` But it looks like your code will also miss the last word.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to work with strings and not raw char arrays but I assume it is with intention that you have decided to use char arrays.

One way to simplify your code is to build the char array as you go instead of preallocating it. .NET arrays have fixed size but `List<T>` allows you to grow a collection of items.

You can also change your function into an iterator block to simplify it further. When a word is complete you `yield return` it to the caller.

```
IEnumerable<char[]> SplitString(char[] str) {
  var word = new List<char>();
  foreach (var ch in str) {
    if (ch == ' ') {
      if (word.Count > 0) {
        yield return word.ToArray();
        word = new List<char>();
      }
    }
    else
      word.Add(ch);
  }
  if (word.Count > 0)
    yield return word.ToArray();
}
```

This function will not return an array so if you want an array of arrays (jagged array) you need to use `ToArray()`:

```
var str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".ToCharArray();
var result = SplitString(str).ToArray();
```

This code will correctly handle multiple spaces and spaces in the beginning and end of the source string.